# How can razor be used to expand CSS templates?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, templates, razor

I am trying to use Razor to generate some CSS. However, I am running into problems with conflicting syntax. Eg:

```
@section css {
<style type="text/css">
    #@(Model.InstanceName) {
        top: @(Model.Properties["top"])px;
    }
</style>
}
```

What is happening is that the first closing curly brace ( } ) is being interpreted by Razor as the end of the @section, instead of the last one. How can I make Razor ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. It appears this is a bug in ASP.NET MVC4 Beta. That will teach me for using beta software.

It works as expected in ASP.NET MVC 3

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.

This would only happen if your HTML tags are imbalanced.
You should either balance your tags or prefix that line with `@:` (or wrap in `<text>` tags) to prevent it from parsing the `}`.

Comment: It doesnt work for me, and the HTML tags arent imbalanced. It works correctly if I remove the @(Model.Properties["top"]) bit but as soon as I put it back the parser gets confused again. Also, putting @: causes a parser error, and wrapping in <text> tags causes the opening tag to get rendered but not the closing tag